# Android GCM notification not displayed on device

Tags: android, notifications, broadcastreceiver, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to add push notification to my android app.
Everything seems ok :

- Sender id is ok
- device is correctly registered to my database
- notification is correctly sent to GCM server (success:1)
- Broadcast receiver correctly receives the message (i see it trough the Eclipse console)

... but the notification is never displayed, although :

- the app is running, or in background
- the "Show/Display notifications" is checked for this app in the general settings of the device
- the permissions seem ok to me...

Here is my code. Any clue about what i did wrong ? Thanks !

Manifest (partial)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<permission android:name="<MY-APP>.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="<MY-APP>.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <receiver
        android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="<MY-APP>" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name=".GcmIntentService" />
```

Broadcast Receiver

```
    package <MY-APP>;
    import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;

    public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.i("gcm_debug", "PushReceiver onReceive called");

    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);

    String msgType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

    if(!extras.isEmpty()){
        if(GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(msgType)){
            Log.i("gcm_debug", "Message send error");
        }else if(GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(msgType)){
            Log.i("gcm_debug", "Message deleted");
        }else if(GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(msgType)){
            Log.i("gcm_debug", "Message received : " + extras.toString());
                }
            }
    setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where did you implemented the notification logic. You have to use the notification manager inside onReceive method of your broadcast receiver for display the notification on your device.

Comment: Nothing in the logcat? Are your GooglePlayServices okay?

Comment: Did u implement the onMessage() method?

Comment: Push notification != notification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gcm push the message to the registered device, and device receive as a message not as Notification.

Please check , your code if you are receiving the message in your device, if yes use the **NotificationManager** to show as notification.

for more details please [check](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) this.

Answer (score 0):

On your Google Play console you need to make sure that the server IP that´s going to send the notification it´s Ok.

You can have a `0.0.0.0/0` ip for your local dev server and a real IP for the production server.

Just like this.

[image]

Comment: According to OP the message is sent successfully.